# How can i forbidden Non-null assertion operator in class properties?

Tags: typescript, eslint

There is eslint role for [no-non-null-assertion](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-non-null-assertion.md).
My question is how can I disallow using non-null assertion in the class properties?

```js
class A{
  someProp!:string
}
```

There is some typescript configuration or eslint role for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [the AST explorer](https://typescript-eslint.io/play/#ts=4.6.2&sourceType=module&showAST=es&code=MYGwhgzhAECCDeBYAUNaED2BbApgBQCcMAHAQgC4IAXAgSwDsBzFAXyA), this production is called a `PropertyDefinition`, and adding the `!` adds `definite: true` to the object. So, you can use the selector `PropertyDefinition[definite=true]` in combination [with `no-restricted-syntax`](https://typescript-eslint.io/docs/linting/troubleshooting/#how-can-i-ban-specific-language-feature).

```
rules: {
    'no-restricted-syntax': ['error',
        {
            selector: 'PropertyDefinition[definite=true]',
            message: 'Non-null property assertions are forbidden',
        },
    ],
},
```

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't work for me (`"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.18.0"` and `"eslint": "^8.12.0"`)